# Add crossdomain.xml to app.yaml file for simple PHP app

Tags: php, google-app-engine, crossdomain.xml, app.yaml

I've problem with editing app.yaml for simple php app has'nt directories that contains 5 files on the root

```
index.php    config.php    welcome.php    share.php    crossdomain.xml
```

my app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: alpha-001
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
script: index.php

- url: /crossdomain.xml 
  mime_type: text/xml
  static_files: static/crossdomain.xml 
  upload: static/crossdomain.xml
```

it return

**Unknown url handler type.**

what's the right way to specify all files in app.yaml

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in the app.yaml as you show it:

- the word `script` (second occurrence) is un-indented (needs two
  spaces before it).
- the `url` regular expressions are tried in order:
  `/.*` will match **any** URL, so the following `/crossdomain.xml`
  handle will **never** trigger.

The first issue can be fixed with miniscule editing, and so can the second one -- you just need to swap the second and third handler directives.

Comment: thanx MR.Alex please your code , you mean `- url:/index.php` instead of `/.*` Sorry , i'm new to GAE platform

Comment: @IFollowMohamed, I mean the second `url` directive in the yaml you posted in your Q, and that is `- url: ./*`; there is no `- url: /index.php` in the yaml you posted, so of course I cannot mean that.